# Horizontal text in radius annotation. [Autocad]

Tags: autocad, cad

I have two files open. One uses horizontal text in radius annotation (see the first picture). The second uses a straight line in radius annotation (see the second picture). I cannot find any difference in the settings of the two files. How do I get the second file's annotation like the first?

Picture 1:
[image]

Picture 2:
[image]

Comment: If you think this is inappropriate for StackOverflow (as I do), go vote for a cad site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93545/computer-aided-design-cad

Answer (score 0):

For a non-programmatic approach, you can import the 'Dimension Style' from one drawing to the other.

Using programming, just enumerate all properties of the style and compare. Below is a code for entities, but you need to adjust for Dim Style:

```
[CommandMethod("compEnt")]
public static void CmdCompareEntities()
{
  Editor ed = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;
  ObjectId id1, id2;

  //select the entities
  PromptEntityResult per1, per2;
  per1 = ed.GetEntity("\nSelect first entity: ");
  id1 = per1.ObjectId;
  per2 = ed.GetEntity("\nSelect second entity: ");
  id2 = per2.ObjectId;

  //some error check
  if (per1.Status != PromptStatus.OK ||
    per2.Status != PromptStatus.OK) return;

  Database db =
    Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database;
  using (Transaction trans =
    db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
  {
    //open the entities
    Entity ent1 = (Entity)trans.GetObject(id1, OpenMode.ForRead);
    Entity ent2 = (Entity)trans.GetObject(id2, OpenMode.ForRead);

    Type entType1 = ent1.GetType();
    Type entType2 = ent2.GetType();

    //the two entities should be the same type
    if (!entType1.Equals(entType2)) return;

    //get the list of properties and iterate
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] props =
      entType1.GetProperties();
    foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop in props)
    {
      try
      {
        //get both values property value
        object val1, val2;
        val1 = prop.GetValue(ent1, null);
        val2 = prop.GetValue(ent2, null);
        if (val1 != null & val2 != null)
        {
          //are equal?
          if (!(val1.Equals(val2)))
          {
            //if not, write the value
            ed.WriteMessage("\n{0} is different: {1}  |  {2}",
                prop.Name, val1.ToString(), val2.ToString());
          }
        }
      }
      catch (Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.Exception ex)
      {
      }
    }
    trans.Commit();
  }
}
```

Source: [Comparing properties of two entities](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/05/comparing-properties-of-two-entities.html)